# How to change short name of days in bootstrap datepiker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to change the short name of days in bootstrap datepiker. 
How to do this?

```
$(".datepicker-wrap input").datepicker({
    isRTL: true,
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    minDate: 1,
    altField: '#alternate2',
    altFormat: 'DD، d MM yy',
    showButtonPanel: true,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the default values in `datepick.js` file.

```
            dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'], /* Change Here*/
            dayNamesShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],  /* Change Here*/
            dayNamesMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],  /* Change Here*/
```

Answer (score 0):

#### String. Default: “mm/dd/yyyy”

The date format, combination of **d, dd, D, DD, m, mm, M, MM, yy, yyyy.**

- d, dd: Numeric date, no leading zero and leading zero, respectively.
  Eg, 5, 05.
- D, DD: Abbreviated and full weekday names, respectively.
  Eg, Mon, Monday.
- m, mm: Numeric month, no leading zero and leading
  zero, respectively. Eg, 7, 07.
- M, MM: Abbreviated and full month
  names, respectively. Eg, Jan, January
- yy, yyyy: 2- and 4-digit years,
  respectively. Eg, 12, 2012.

### Custom formatting options

toDisplay: function (date, format, language) to convert date object to string, that will be stored in input field
toValue: function (date, format, language) to convert string object to date, that will be used in date selection

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: {
        /*
         * Say our UI should display a week ahead,
         * but textbox should store the actual date.
         * This is useful if we need UI to select local dates,
         * but store in UTC
         */
        toDisplay: function (date, format, language) {
            var d = new Date(date);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
            return d.toISOString();
        },
        toValue: function (date, format, language) {
            var d = new Date(date);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
            return new Date(d);
        }
    },
    autoclose: true
});
```

---

link is [here]: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#format